# Python2.7: Ensure 3D list of objects are unique

Tags: python, list, object, memory

I'm using a 3D list of objects in Python to organize a data set that I have. I'm noticing that my object elements are not quite unique i.e. variables inside one object of the array are being updated in others. A minimal working example that illustrates my issue is shown below.

```
class myClass:
        def __init__(self,ListA=[],ListB=[],ListCount=0):
                self.ListA = ListA
                self.ListB = ListB
                self.ListCount = ListCount

        def add_data(self,ElementA,ElementB):
                self.ListA.append(ElementA)
                self.ListB.append(ElementB)
                self.ListCount = self.ListCount + 1

        def check_data(self):
                if(len(self.ListA) != self.ListCount):
                        print("Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object!")
                        print("Object has %d elements. Thinks it has %d"%(len(self.ListA),self.ListCount))
```

The python code that uses this class definition goes something like this.

```
import random

ObjectArray = [[[myClass() for k in range(4)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
#Print addresses of object array
print("Addresses of the individual object elements in the 3D list ")
for i in range(0,2):
        for j in range(0,3):
                for k in range(0,4):
                        print(ObjectArray[i][j][k])

#Loop over object array and fill each object with some data
for i in range(0,2):
        for j in range(0,3):
                for k in range(0,4):

                        NumData = int(10*random.random())

                        for m in range(0,NumData):

                                #Generate some junk data to insert into the list of this object
                                ListAData = int(10*random.random())
                                ListBData = int(10*random.random())

                                ObjectArray[i][j][k].check_data()
                                ObjectArray[i][j][k].add_data(ListAData,ListBData)
                                ObjectArray[i][j][k].check_data()
```

What have I missed? Is it possible to use 3D lists of objects in Python 2.7? Each object in the list appears to have a unique memory address when I print it out. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

A sample of the output from this code is:

```
Addresses of the individual object elements in the 3D list 
<__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad4ef80> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad635a8> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad63248> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad63440>
 <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d320> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad6d368> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad6d3b0> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d3f8>
 <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d488> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad6d4d0> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad6d518> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d560>
 <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d638> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad6d680> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad6d6c8> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d710>
 <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d7a0> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad6d7e8> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad6d830> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d878>
 <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d908> <__main__.myClass
 instance at 0x7fc59ad6d950> <__main__.myClass instance at
 0x7fc59ad6d998> <__main__.myClass instance at 0x7fc59ad6d9e0> 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 4 elements. Thinks it has 0
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 5 elements. Thinks it has 1 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 5 elements. Thinks it has 1 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 6 elements. Thinks it has 2 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 6 elements. Thinks it has 2 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 7 elements. Thinks it has 3 
Error: Unaccounted for Data in Object! Object has 7 elements. Thinks it has 3
```

Comment: they are unique instances of myClass but if you print the `print(id(ObjectArray[i][j][k].ListA))` you should see they all have the same list .... search for "mutable default arguments in python"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change it to

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,ListA=None,ListB=None,ListCount=0):
            self.ListA = [] if ListA is None else ListA
            self.ListB = [] if ListB is None else ListB
            self.ListCount = ListCount
```

this will avoid the mutable default arguments

consider the following

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,a=[],b=None):
        self.a = a
        print "ID of a:",id(a)
        if b is not None:
           self.a.append(b)

print MyClass(b=5).a
print MyClass(b=6).a
print MyClass(b=7).a
```

note that each of the MyClass has a unique memory location, however all 3 point to the same array (the default argument for a)

Comment: That is exactly the solution to my issue @JoranBeasley. For others, here is a webpage with more information on the common issue for new Python programmers of mutable default arguments.

[Mutable Default Arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)